# As3 List down the Printers that available in the system

Tags: actionscript-3

How to list down all the printers in system in ActionScript 3.
as3 property printers not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var printerList:Vector.<String> = PrintJob.printers;
var p:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
if (printerList) for (var i:int = 0; i < printerList.length; i++) p.addItem(printerList[i]);
```