# as3 list all available printer

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to list down all available printers that are availble. I found this answer:
[As3 List down the Printers that available in the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221646/as3-list-down-the-printers-that-available-in-the-system)
But this doesn't work, I'm getting this error:

Error: Access of possibly undefined property printers through a reference with static type Class.

this is my source:

```
package  
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.printing.PrintJob;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

public class gethwinfo extends Sprite
{

    public function gethwinfo() 
    {
        ExternalInterface.call('getPrinter', getPrinterList());
    }

    public function getPrinterList():Array
    {
        var printerList:Vector.<String> = PrintJob.printers;
        var deviceNames:Array = [];

        if (printerList)
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < printerList.length; i++)
            {
                deviceNames.push(printerList[i]);
            }
        } else
        {
            deviceNames.push("No Printers");
        }

        deviceNames.sort();
        return deviceNames;
    }   
}
}
```

The Error says that the property printers is undefined, although this property is listed in the as-reference: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html#printers

I get this error with strict mode set to true in the compiler options. When I set it to false the build is sucessfull, but when I call this flash object it goes into the else branch and I get the String "No Printers", which should not be, because I have 6 printer services available on my machine.

I hope that you can give me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its only available in AIR. thats why the AIR icon is next to it in the as-reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed the Platform to AIR 3.5, now it builds without an error, but it still goes through the else branch. I use the Flex SDK 4.6.0 and AIR 3.5. Strict mode is set to true.

Comment: PrintJob.printers: If no printers are available or if the system does not support printing, the value is null.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense, but there are printers available on my system. I wrote a Java applet, that does show me 6 printers (or printer services)available, and I wanted to do the same with Actionscript. I'll mark your answer as a solution, since the main problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: java applet has different security, so it won't necessary will be the same.